# How to fill background color to the parent element's height?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

While making cards, I have one difficult problem. I want to fill background-color whole box content, but I am a beginner in html and css, so I don't know how to do.
My codes are bellow.

```css
.box-container1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #3AD6B1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px #ddd;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 8px;
  width: 420px;
}

.box .box-header {
  background-color: #3AD6B1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 4rem;
}

.box .box-img {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.box .box-content {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-align: left;
}

.bg-green {
  background-color: #3AD6B1!important;
}

.bg-green01 {
  background-color: #1CA484;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="box-container1">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-header">
      <div class="bg-green01 text-white p-2 font-weight-bold">
        <div class="h3 m-0">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="font-weight-bold p-2 text-left">Box 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-img"><img src="assets/img/Team-presentation.png"></div>
    <div class="bg-green01 w-100" style="height: 1rem"></div>
    <div class="box-content">
      <label>This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text.</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-header">
      <div class="bg-green01 text-white p-2 font-weight-bold">
        <div class="h3 m-0">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="font-weight-bold p-2 text-left">Box 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-img"><img src="assets/img/Coding.png"></div>
    <div class="bg-green01 w-100" style="height: 1rem"></div>
    <div class="box-content">
      <label>This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text.</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you try out my code, you can find that the background-color does not fill in case box2.
But I want to fill the card content.
I want to sole this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add two `flex` rules `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` for selector `.box`.

Also, add rule `flex: 1` for selector `.box .box-content`. To stretch over the entire free space.

And change the `margin` to `padding`, in the same selector.

```css
.box-container1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #3AD6B1;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px #ddd;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 8px;
    width: 420px;
}
.box .box-header {
    background-color: #3AD6B1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    height: 4rem;
}
.box .box-img {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.box .box-content {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    text-align: left;
    flex: 1;
}
.bg-green {
    background-color: #3AD6B1!important;
}
.bg-green01 {
    background-color: #1CA484;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container1">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header">
            <div class="bg-green01 text-white p-2 font-weight-bold">
                <div class="h3 m-0">1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="font-weight-bold p-2 text-left">Box 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-img"><img src="assets/img/Team-presentation.png"></div>
        <div class="bg-green01 w-100" style="height: 1rem"></div>
        <div class="box-content">
            <label>This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text.</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header">
            <div class="bg-green01 text-white p-2 font-weight-bold">
                <div class="h3 m-0">2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="font-weight-bold p-2 text-left">Box 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-img"><img src="assets/img/Coding.png"></div>
        <div class="bg-green01 w-100" style="height: 1rem"></div>
        <div class="box-content">
            <label>This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text.</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @George, I've added instructions on how to achieve this. Glad was to help.